# initializing struct pointer to null

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null

I am trying to build a hash table, using the following node and table:

```
typedef struct Node {
   int key;
   int value;
   int status;     
} Node;

typedef struct Table {
   int size;
   Node* node;
} Table;
```

`node` in struct `Table` is a `Node` pointer so I thought `hasht(Table*)->node` would be a `Node*`. I tried to initialize all the `node*` in the table to `NULL` like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<hasht->size;i++)
{
   hasht->node[i]=NULL;
}
```

However, when I compile the code it give me this error:

> " incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Node {aka struct Node}’ from type ‘void *’
>      hasht->node[i]=NULL; "

I don't understand why `hasht->node[i]` is a `Node`, not a `Node*`. 
How can I get a `Node*` member in the `Table` variable with a `Table*`?

Answer (score 1):

`hasht->node` is a `Node *`, which can be a pointer to a single `Node` or a pointer to an array of `Node` objects. `hasht->node[i]` then refers to the `i`th `Node` object in such an array. Note that by definition, for a pointer `p`, `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)`.

If you want your table to have an array of nodes, you can use it as-is, but then there's nothing to null out, because there are actual `Node` objects in the table.

If, on the other hand, you want an array of *pointers to nodes* for some reason, you'll need to change the table member to `Node **node`. Then, you can have it point to an array of pointers to `Node`, which can indeed be nulled out individually (since `hasht->node[i]` would be a `Node *` then). You'll get memory fragmentation and be cache-unfriendly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to initialize struct pointer to NULL?

> I tried to initialize all the node* in the table to NULL like this:

There is only one pointer and I suppose  you need to allocate some memory for it:

```
hasht->node = calloc(hasht->size, sizeof(Node));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index is in the wrong place. You need

`hasht[i]->node=NULL;` (and not `hasht->node[i]=NULL;`)